# How to move two html elements (<th> & <td>) closer to each other?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I know this is probably super basic but I cannot figure it out. I would like to move the name closer to the title that is on the same row, however it is displaying across the screen. This is what my code looks like:

```css
th.tableTitle {
  background-color: #E3E5EE;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial Narrow, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

th.headerLabel {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial Narrow, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

td.dataResponse {
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial Narrow, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*border-bottom: 1pt #BFBFBF solid; */
}
```

```html
<table class="displayTable" , width="80%">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="12" class="tableTitle">STUDENT INFORMATION</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" class="headerLabel">Student Name:</th>
    <td colspan="10" class="dataResponse">Max</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

`padding-bottom` adds extra space. So just remove it

```css
th.tableTitle {
  background-color: #E3E5EE;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial Narrow, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

th.headerLabel {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial Narrow, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

td.dataResponse {
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial Narrow, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*border-bottom: 1pt #BFBFBF solid; */
}
```

```html
<table class="displayTable" , width="80%">
    <tr>
      <th colspan="12" class="tableTitle">STUDENT INFORMATION</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2" class="headerLabel">Student Name:</th>
      <td colspan="10" class="dataResponse">Max</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**UPDATE:**

Your table `width` is `80%` of screen and table has just two columns. So text in these two columns has big two gaps. What you can do is to set tighter `width`. Or if you want to keep current width align text to the right `text-align: right;`:

```
th.headerLabel {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial Narrow, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: This is true but I am trying to remove the space between the elements on the same row, my <th> and <td> aka Student name: and Max

Comment: @Maximilian please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, remove the colspan from the th and td and set width of th field to 1% so that it's width is not set based on the amount of text it has then disable word wrap on the heads or something else so it stays on same line

```css
th.tableTitle {
  background-color: #E3E5EE;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial Narrow, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}

th.headerLabel {
  background-color: red;
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial Narrow, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap
}

td.dataResponse {
  color: black;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial Narrow, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  /*border-bottom: 1pt #BFBFBF solid; */
}
```

```html
<table class="displayTable" , width="80%">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="12" class="tableTitle">STUDENT INFORMATION</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 1%" class="headerLabel">Student Name:</th>
    <td class="dataResponse">Max</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```